# How to move data stored locally to BigTable when deploying Django?

Tags: django, google-cloud-datastore, djangoappengine

I am using [djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/djangoappengine) to deploy a Django app on Google App Engine. I have a lot of data already stored locally, and when I deploy the project with GAE it disappears. How do I get this data to carry over from the dbindexer to the BigTable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the GAE documentation re: uploading and downloading data:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

It contains the information you need to upload your locally stored data to GAE.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and I think I need to use fixtures: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures

Comment: actually, there is another problem. I dumped the data to initial_data.json, then did syncdb, and deployed. It did tell me that it found a fixture with a bunch of objects, but they are not displaying on either the admin or the site. Is there anything else I need to do (maybe change settings.py?)

Comment: Got it fixed. Had to run **remote** syncdb instead of just syncdb.